# How to Animate an Element Back to Its Original Position with CSS3 @keyframes

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I see how I would do it if I was using `transition` but I need an infinitely recurring animation at one point (I'd also like to know if infinite transitions are possible; heh).  Visit [www.terrasoftlabs.com](http://www.terrasoftlabs.com) for the problem in action.  When you hover over the images, the transition to the spinning occurs perfectly.  However, when your mouse leaves that area, the element *snaps* back into place.  What is the solution for this?  I have seen many similar questions here but none of the solutions seemed to fit the bill.  I appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

infinite animations are possible: check this demo out: http://ludonaut.de/mario/

Comment: he asked for infinite animations, i delivered. allowing users to downvote without making them accountable is for the fail. i mean the trololololololol

Comment: What I am looking for is a way for when the animation ends for it to smoothly transition to its original state.  The one on my site is infinite as long as it is being hovered.

Comment: ok, idk if this works on :hover, but i think this be what you want: http://joelb.me/blog/2012/maintaining-css-style-states-using-infinite-transition-delays/